# Regex to extract option names into specific select

Tags: html, jmeter

In Jmeter, I need to extract values from a dropdown list in a response. For simplifying, I have this response :

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <select id="toto" style="width:100px;">
            <option selected name="name1" value="value 1"></option>
            <option selected name="name2" value="value 2"></option>
            <option selected name="name3" value="value 3"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select id="tutu" style="width:100px;">
            <option selected name="name1" value="value 1"></option>
            <option selected name="name2" value="value 2"></option>
            <option selected name="name3" value="value 3"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I need to extract name1, name2 and name3 from the second select (id="tutu"). I can't use XPath because my HTML file is not a valid XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor), give `select[id=tutu] > option` as the "Selector" and `name` as the "Attribute"

[image]

More information:

- [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)
- [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor)

---

Also it should be possible to use XPath Extractor if you tick `Use Tidy` box, however CSS Selector Extractor works faster and consumes less resources so if you can get what you want using CSS selectors - go for it:

[image]